# On MacOS is it possible to export Intellij IDEA or Eclipse as X Windows applications?

Tags: eclipse, macos, intellij-idea, x11

I could export xeyes between two MPBs via the X windows protocol.

What other applications can I export like this?

With Intellij IDEA I could do it from a Docker container running Linux.

I wonder, would it be possible to export the native Intellij over X?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, due to the fact that the protocol used in Mac for GUIs is VNC, not X. However this makes so that VNC can be used remotely. It is true that the quality would be better with X due to local input (mouse, keyboard) instantly reflected locally and then sent upstream, which makes it snappy at interactions.